# Android SQLite Query with IN()

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the following Models

categories(id, name, is_active)
places(id, name, category_id, .....)

Based on users preferences the categories will be `0 or 1`. Based on this preference i want to query all the places whose `categories.is_active = 1`.

I think there is two approaches

**First Approach**

1. Query and get all Categories whose is_active = 1
2. Get a list of all the places from the above retrieved collection of Category ids.

**Second Approach**

Writing a RawQuery with JOIN and set the condition.

Which is the best way to do it to optimize speed ?

What i have tried ?

```
// Get Active Categories
public Cursor getActiveCategories() {
    return db.query(TABLE_CATEGORIES, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
            COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_SLUG, COLUMN_ACTIVE }, COLUMN_ACTIVE + "="
            + "'1'", null, null, null, COLUMN_NAME, null);
}


// Get Places
public Cursor getPlaces() {
    return db.query(TABLE_PLACES, new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME },
            " type IN ('1','2')", null, null, null, null);
}
```

In the above code how to insert the type `IN ('1','2')` dynamically so that i can populate that from the result from the first method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single rawQuery will almost always be faster than two separate queries. Since you don't have any parameters in the rawQuery, it will be pretty simple, something like;

```
SELECT places.* 
FROM places 
JOIN categories
  ON places.category_id = categories.id
WHERE categories.is_active = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If i want to add all the columns from the table places also. how can i do that ?